# Parsing Attribute Routed URL in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I'm trying to get the parameters of specific attribute routed URL on ActionFilterAttribute. For instance I have an action like below:

```
[Route("/v1/test/{userId}/{udid}")]
public object GetNewObject(int userId, string udid)
```

And in action filter attribute the absolute url is coming something like "http://test.example.com/v1/test/1/123-asda-231-asd". However I want to parse these parameters as userId=1 and udid=... within a collection.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Anyway I found the answer,

Within RouteData of ControllerContext we may able to retrieve the specified value.

```
actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["udid"]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Route("...")] is possible only in MVC 5.
I think you want to do something like this

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/users
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<User> Get() { ... }

    // GET api/user/5
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public Book Get(int id) { ... }

    // POST api/users
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(User book) { ... }
}
```

where each User contains your properties

```
public class User
{
     int UserId{get;set;}
     string Udid{get; set;} 
}
```